# Toggle Element that is clicked and hide all other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure how I can toggle an element that is clicked and then hide all other elements, only when close the other elements will appear again.

Here is the website that I am working on.

http://digitalspin.ph/test/manosa/campanilla-features-2/

Basically when the user clicks on the "point of interest". A small window will appear, and then hiding all other "points of interest" on the screen. If the user decides to close the small. The other points of interest will appear.

**Here is the HTML Structure**

```
<div class="poi poi-one">
    <form>
        <button class="show-poi-window" type="button">X</button>
    </form>
    <div class="poi-window hide animated">
        <img src="http://localhost/man/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/solid-carbonized-strandwoven-bamboo.png">
        <div class="poi-description">
            <form>
                <input class="close-poi-window" type="button" value="X">
            </form>
             <h2>Solid Carbonized Strandwoven Bamboo </h2>

            <p>The rich earthly shade of the Solid Carbonized Strandwoven Bamboo for the flooring genuinely expresses authentic Filipino home design, aside from being nature and environment friendly as well.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button.show-poi-window').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('div').find('.poi-window').addClass('fadeIn').removeClass('hide fadeOut');
        $('button.show-poi-window').addClass('fadeOut').removeClass('fadeIn')
        $('#slider ul.slides li').append('<div class="slide-overlay"></div>');
    })

    $('input.close-poi-window').click(function () {
        $('.poi-window').removeClass('fadeIn').addClass('fadeOut');
        $('button.show-poi-window').addClass('fadeIn').removeClass('fadeOut');
        $('.slide-overlay').remove();
    })

})
```

Comment: Add your code in jsfiddle or snippet so i can debug your script.

Comment: Yeah, you're posting Javascript with selectors that are not present in the HTML you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...

first of all make use of the ids in you html code

**Your HTML shall look like this**

```
  <div class="poi" id="poi1">
     ...your content for this goes here.....
  </div>

  <button class="button.show-poi-window">Click Me</button>

  <div class="poi" id="poi2">
     ...your content for this goes here....
  </div>

  <button class="input.close-poi-window">Click Me</button>
```

**Here goes your JavaScript**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('button.show-poi-window').click(function(){
         $('.poi-window').hide();
         $('#poi1').show();            
      });


      $('input.close-poi-window').click(function(){
          $('.poi-window').hide();
          $('#poi2').show();              
      });
  });
```

And that is how you can show/hide your contents, rest of the appending and animation part can be integrated according you own interest, thank you very much...